# BST delete - delete "tmp" causes lose of the tree

Tags: binary-search-tree

[debug result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR79l.jpg)

Attached my code for trying to delete a node in bst.

If I want to delete node 1, when specifying tmp = del in "if (del_node->l_ == NULL)", and remove tmp, then del is removed as well, and the tree data is lost. how can I solve this issue?

Example tree:

```
  3
 / \
1   5
 \ 
  2
```

- all data members and functions are declared public for simplicity.

  ```
    void BST::DeleteNode(int data) {
        BinaryTreeNode* &del_node = BST_Search(head_, data);
        if (!del_node->l_ && !del_node->r_)
        {
            delete del_node;
            del_node = nullptr;
            return;
        }
        if (del_node->l_ == NULL)
        {
            BinaryTreeNode* tmp = del_node;
            del_node = del_node->r_;
            tmp = nullptr;
            delete tmp;
            return;
        }
        if (del_node->r_ == NULL)
        {
            BinaryTreeNode* tmp = del_node;
            del_node = del_node->l_;
            delete tmp;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            del_node->data_ = smallestRightSubTree(del_node->r_);
        }

    }

    int BST::smallestRightSubTree(BinaryTreeNode* rightroot)
    {
        // if rightroot has no more left childs
        if (rightroot && !rightroot->l_)
        {
            int tmpVal = rightroot->data_;
            BinaryTreeNode* tmp = rightroot;
            rightroot = rightroot->r_;
            delete tmp;
            return tmpVal;
        }
        return smallestRightSubTree(rightroot->l_);
    }
    int main()
    {
        BST bst;
        bst.BST_Insert(bst.head_, 3);
        bst.BST_Insert(bst.head_, 5);
        bst.BST_Insert(bst.head_, 1);
        bst.BST_Insert(bst.head_, 2);
        bst.DeleteNode(1);
        return 0;
    }
  ```

Thanks for help!
EDIT: this is how tmp and del_node look like after the line "del_node = del_node->r_)" in the condition "if(del->l = null)"

```
void BST::BST_Insert(BinaryTreeNode*& head, int data) {
if (head == nullptr) {
    head = new BinaryTreeNode(data, nullptr, nullptr);
    return;
}
if (data > head->data_) {
    BST_Insert(head->r_, data);
}
else {
    BST_Insert(head->l_, data);
}
```

}

```
BinaryTreeNode* BST::BST_Search(BinaryTreeNode* root, int key) {
    if (root == nullptr || root->data_ == key)
        return root;
    if (key > root->data_)
        return BST_Search(root->r_, key);
    return BST_Search(root->l_, key);
}
```

Comment: `tmp = nullptr; delete tmp;` Does not free up any memory. it merely forgets the value of the pointer that was in tmp. Not sure what "tree data is lost" means. You should probably take a debugger to this and observe the method in action. Or make a proper [mre] so that we could see the problem. Or both.

Comment: [traditional note about debuggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Thanks for comment. Took away the "tmp=nullptr", the thing is, that the tree is constructed as I expect. however, when Im inside of the delete method, "del_node" gets the address of node 1, "tmp" gets the same address in memory as del_node. when del_node is promoted to point its right child, the data in del_node and tmp is deleted.. (maybe wrong use of the delete operator?) Attached screenshot from the debugger in the original post. THANKS

Comment: If after this piece of code del_node points off into the void which could be the stack then the suspicion would fall on `BST_Search` not doing quite the right thing and you haven't shown us what's in that. The demands for a [mre] are not just to inconvenience you, there's a point to it...

Comment: Sorry! Didn't notice. Added those functions as well. Still trying to understand what is not working.. Isn't it related to the face that I delete a pointer? maybe since they hold the same address, deleting one causes the deletion of the other? I have been debugging this for the last two hours, but for some reason, the del_node and tmp are becoming null after the line of "delete tmp"

Comment: What does the line `BinaryTreeNode* &del_node = BST_Search(head_, data);` do when initialized with the rvalue from `BinaryTreeNode* BST::BST_Search` ? This allocates a temporary on the stack and the reference is to that temporary (I believe this should emit a warning). You probably intended it to be a reference to the original variable holding the pointer.

Comment: So your search should be taking its argument as and returning a pointer reference as well. (not sure I'm making this very clear, it is somewhat complicated)

Comment: Maybe this would be easier with `**` instead of `*&`, at least with the double-star code the compiler does not let you mistake a one-star pointer for a two-star one.

Answer (score 0):

If your `BST_Search` returns a `BinaryTreeNode*` by value, what is the reference in `BinaryTreeNode* &del_node = BST_Search(head_, data);` actually referencing? It allocates a new temporary and references that. You probably wanted it to reference the variable that is holding the pointer in the tree so that you can modify the tree.

Your BST_Search would have to look like this:

```
BinaryTreeNode*& BST::BST_Search(BinaryTreeNode*& root, int key) {
    if (root == nullptr || root->data_ == key)
        return root;
    if (key > root->data_)
        return BST_Search(root->r_, key);
    return BST_Search(root->l_, key);
}
```

I can't check whether this actually works, because you didn't provide a self-contained compilable example. But something along these lines.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I had been debugging this fir hours! Could you explain me why the version without the ref to pointer in search didnt work? I thought thats how you return an address.. and again, thank you!

Comment: Imagine if you wanted to delete `root` (bst.root? not sure how you named it). You want to be able to change the value of the pointer inside the `root` variable. If you search for it using the old search, you get its value (pointer to the first node). Can you use this value to assign a different pointer value to the `root` variable? You would need to get a reference to the variable to be able to do that, not just its value.

Comment: Alternative view: your `del_node` was a copy. When you change it, you are changing your copy only, not the original. You need to get a reference to the original somehow.